# Does NVD3.js include a built-in option to set the color of each Y-axis?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, nvd3.js

I have one of NVD3.js's line plus bar charts configured as below. Of course, each series of data has its own color for the bar/line display on the chart. I'm curious if there's a built-in way to set the Y-axis associated with a particular series to the same color as that series. In my example below, that would mean that:

a) the left axis and the bar chart would be "steelblue"

b) the right axis and the line chart would be "skyblue"

I stepped through the NVD3 and D3 code a little bit looking at the axis objects, but I didn't find anything that seemed like it would set this sort of an option.

Thanks in advance for any insight into this feature, present or otherwise!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Line + Bar Chart | NVD3.js</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="nv.d3.css"/>
    <style>
        #chart svg {
            height: 400px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chart">
        <svg></svg>
    </div>
    <script src="d3.js"></script>
    <script src="nv.d3.js"></script>
    <script>
        var data = [
            {
                'key': 'foo',
                'bar': true,
                'color': 'skyblue',
                'values': [
                    [1431993600000, 31.6882],
                    [1432080000000, 76.1706],
                    [1432166400000, 76.2297],
                    [1432252800000, 75.1944],
                    [1432339200000, 75.1536],
                    [1432425600000, 74.528],
                    [1432512000000, 75.7265],
                    [1432598400000, 75.8659],
                    [1432684800000, 74.6283],
                    [1432771200000, 73.3533]
                ]
            },
            {
                'key': 'bar',
                'color': 'steelblue',
                'values': [
                    [1431993600000, 0.0002997961386257345],
                    [1432080000000, 0.0004418193656404055],
                    [1432166400000, 0.0003122142681920564],
                    [1432252800000, 0.00031651293181407124],
                    [1432339200000, 0.0003845457835685849],
                    [1432425600000, 0.00031934306569343066],
                    [1432512000000, 0.0005163317993040745],
                    [1432598400000, 0.00042575122683577205],
                    [1432684800000, 0.00025057518394496457],
                    [1432771200000, 0.00041715914621428076]
                ]
            }
        ];
        nv.addGraph(function () {
            var chart = nv.models.linePlusBarChart()
                    .margin({
                        top: 30,
                        right: 60,
                        bottom: 50,
                        left: 70
                    })
                    .x(function (d, i) {
                        return i;
                    })
                    .y(function (d, i) {
                        return d[1];
                    })
                    .options({
                        focusEnable: false,
                        showLegend: false
                    });

            chart.xAxis
                    .showMaxMin(true)
                    .tickFormat(function (d) {
                        var dx = data[0].values[d] && data[0].values[d][0] || 0;
                        return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(dx));
                    });

            chart.y1Axis
                    .tickFormat(d3.format(',f'));

            chart.y2Axis
                    .tickFormat(function (d) {
                        return d3.format('g')(d)
                    });

            chart.bars.forceY([0, 200]);
            chart.lines.forceY([0]);

            d3.select('#chart svg')
                    .datum(data)
                    .transition()
                    .duration(0)
                    .call(chart);

            nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

            return chart;
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.nv-y1 {
    fill: steelblue;
}
.nv-y2 {
    fill: skyblue;
}
rect {
    fill: steelblue;
}
path {
    stroke: skyblue;
}
```

Just use CSS for that.